# Microsoft Dynamics 365 OData service does not use display names

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, powerbi, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm using Dynamics 365 version 8.2 on-premise and I've found that the the default OData service (https://CRM/api/data/v8.2/) displays entity and field names using the **Name** field and not the **Display Name**.

This is unfortunate because I was hoping to encourage non technical users who are familiar with the UI display names to use the service through tools like Excel or Power BI.

Is there anyway I can customise the builtin OData service or correct this?

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: Well, I'm still stuck... but at least I now know it's not my configuration... so yes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema names returned by web api - this is by design. As the schema name is unique & cannot be changed like display names anytime.

You (technical team) can create the data model with the display names using metadata api calls, so non-tech people can use that data model for their usage.